# How to move files based on name correspondence with a folder?

Tags: linux, move

I have this parent directory X and these two subdirectories A and B (see Photo 1):[image] Folder A contains files for specific subjects that I want to move to further corresponding folders within Folder B. For example, in folder A, I have a lot of files for different subjects that end with different extensions (eeg.eeg, eeg.json, eeg.vhdr, and eeg.vmrk) (see Photo 2).[image]

I want to take all these files for each subject and move them to subfolders of B, where there is a subfolder for all subjects: B>>"subject_id">>ses-t1>>eeg. The destination folders should be the "eeg" folders in each participant's folder. [image].

The desired result should be as is depicted in the photo below (Photo 3):
[image]

The good thing is, I think, that the starting name of the files in folder A, correspond with the subject subfolder name. For example, the file starts with **sub-CDPC0001**_ses-01_task-rest_eeg.eeg, which is similar to the subject folder for this particular subject within folder B (**sub_CDPC0001)**

In the past, there has been a mini script used for this, but I don't think works properly on this arrangement right now:

```
for dir in $(ls -d */ses-t1); do
find "./$dir/" -name '*_eeg.eeg' -exec mv {} "$dir/eeg" \;
find "./$dir/" -name '*_eeg.vhdr' -exec mv {} "$dir/eeg" \;
find "./$dir/" -name '*_eeg.vmrk' -exec mv {} "$dir/eeg" \;
find "./$dir/" -name '*_eeg.json' -exec mv {} "$dir/eeg" \;
#find "./$dir/" -name '*_anat.nii.gz' -exec mv {} "$dir/t1" \;
done
```

This lists all the files from folder A but fails to move them to the desired eeg folder.
I would appreciate an answer very much, as there are a lot of data, and moving them manually is prone to error and very tedious.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.  In this case, it's probably best to post a **minimally comprehensive** excerpt from the output of `find A/ B/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install the perl `rename` utility.  You seem to be using a Mac, so you'll probably need to use [brew](https://brew.sh/), it has perl rename packaged - see https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename.

Once that's installed, you should be able to run something like:

```
$ find A/ -regex '.*_eeg.\(eeg\|vhdr\|vmrk\|json\)' \
    -exec rename -n 's=^.*/(sub-[^_]*)_=B/$1/eeg/$1_=' {} +
```

NOTE: I'm not sure exactly which version of `find` is installed on Macs these days.  I'm assuming it's a FreeBSD's version of `find` and has a `-regex` predicate.  If not, use `brew` to install GNU `find` and use that instead of the default Mac `find`.  Without `-regex` you could do it by OR-ing several -name predicates together (in parentheses to force precedence):

```
find A/ \( -name '*_eeg.eeg' -o -name '*_eeg.vhdr' -o -name '*_eeg.vmrk' -o -name '*_eeg.json' \) -exec rename ...`
```

Also note that rename's `-n` option makes it a dry run, so it will only show what it
would do without actually renaming any files. Remove the `-n`, or replace it
with `-v` for verbose output, when you've confirmed that it does what you
want.  Modify the rename script if it's not quite right until it works as you want it.

BTW, this assumes that B/*subject*/ and B/*subject*/eeg/ already exist.  If they don't and you want the rename script to create the directories before renaming the files, insert the following immediately before the `s===` substitution operation.

```
if (m=^.*/(sub-[^_]*)_=) { mkdir "B/$1"; mkdir "B/$1/eeg" };
```

Sample run (with only one filename because I couldn't be bothered typing in more filenames from your [pictures of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) for the `touch` command, but it would work with the .vhdr, .vmrk, and .json files too if they existed in my A/ directory):

```
$ mkdir -p A B/sub-CDPC0001/eeg/
$ touch A/sub-CDPC0001_ses-01_task-rest_eeg.eeg

$ find A/ -regex '.*_eeg.\(eeg\|vhdr\|vmrk\|json\)' \
    -exec rename -v 's=^.*/(sub-[^_]*)_=B/$1/eeg/$1_=' {} +
A/sub-CDPC0001_ses-01_task-rest_eeg.eeg renamed as B/sub-CDPC0001/eeg/sub-CDPC0001_ses-01_task-rest_eeg.eeg
```